# pandas to datetime strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dates as text in the same format:

The first is December 1st 2019:

```
'01-12-19 01:04'
```

The second is May 24th 2019:

```
'24-05-19 15:02'
```

I want to convert it to `datetime` using `pandas`.

This is the results of `pd.to_datetime()`

```
Timestamp('2019-05-24 15:02:00')

Timestamp('2019-01-12 01:04:00')
```

The first one is correct but for the second one I get 12th January 2019 and it should be 1st December 2019.

Why is that?

Comment: Specify the format. The second case is ambiguous and `pd.to_datetime` is only guessing from the order

Comment: may be you need `pd.to_datetime(...,dayfirst=True)`

Comment: I'm honestly just guessing, but maybe since the time for the second one is 24h it assumes that it's dd-mm-yy, and the time for the first one could be 12h pm/am and it assumes that it's mm-dd-yy?

Comment: @kakkeuno: just guessing too, but as 24 cannot be a valid month  number, `pd.to_datetime` can infer that it can only be a day...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, that makes more sense than my guess!

Comment: Hi, thanks, the solution @anky_91 suggested works